# Selecting an entire column in Range

Tags: excel

With excel vba , I have the column number  stored in a variable (let's say x)  and need to find a string in that column 
The number of rows in that column would vary and cannot be hard coded.
I want to use Range.Find method and looking for something like this

```
 Set rng =Worksheet.Range().find(...)
if Not rng is Nothing .....
```

So wondering what should go into Range() that would use column number x

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Worksheet.Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.columns) method to refer to an entire column range.

Your code should be the following:

```
Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(X).Find(...)
If Not Rng Is Nothing Then ...
```

Note: `Range.Find` will return "**[Nothing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)**" if it doesn't find a match.